# Condição if... else.... c# firebase

Tags: c#, firebase

Boa Tarde, Eu tenho uma condição If.. else.. porém ambas retornam verdadeiras quando são absolutamente contrarias.
O suposto é a aplicação verificar se o username e a password estão presentes na base de dados (firebase) e caso isso aconteça a aplicação prossegue para o próximo form, caso contrário, aparece uma MessageBox de erro a dizer que algum dos campos está errado.
No entanto o que está a acontecer é que, mesmo quando os campos de texto, username e password, se verificam presentes na base de dados, aparece erro, e depois de confirmar a MessageBox a aplicação prossegue como senão tivesse acontecido nenhum erro.
Aqui está o codigo:

```
    private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Login

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(PassTxt.Text))
        {

            //Check if textbox is Empty
            var result = RJMessageBox.Show(" Please enter data for all fields ",
                "Error!!",
                MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            //Looping to get the match data using foreach
            FirebaseResponse response = client.Get("Users/");
            Dictionary<string, Registe> result = response.ResultAs<Dictionary<string, Registe>>();

            foreach (var get in result)
            {
                string userresult = get.Value.username;
                string premiumresult = get.Value.Premium;
                string passresult = get.Value.password;
                string emailresult = get.Value.email;
                string fnameresult = get.Value.FullName;

                **// Erro, aparece a messageBox como entra no Formulario**
                if ((UserTxt.Text != userresult) && (PassTxt.Text != passresult))
                {
                    var result2 = RJMessageBox.Show("Credentials do not exist",
                        "Error!!",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    usernamepass = UserTxt.Text;
                    fullname = fnameresult;
                    pass = PassTxt.Text;
                    mail = emailresult;
                    RPre = premiumresult;

                    if (RPre == "0")
                    {
                        VPNFree VPNFree = new VPNFree();
                        this.Hide();
                        VPNFree.ShowDialog();
                    }

                    if (RPre == "1")
                    {
                        VPN VPN = new VPN();
                        this.Hide();
                        VPN.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
                **// Erro, aparece a messageBox como entra no Formulario**
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo oque analisei o seu código o fato de mesmo aparecendo a mensagem e continuar a executar se da pois ele não sai em nenhum momento do foreach, assim percorrendo todos os usuários mesmo achando ou não a conta desejada.

Fiz algumas modificações no seu código que pode ser que funcione da maneira correta.

1. Adicionei uma variável dynamic para salvar a conta quando for encontrada.
2. Adicionei uma variável bool para verificar se foi encontrada.
3. Coloquei o seu if .. else fora do foreach.
4. Dentro do foreach coloquei para verificar se a conta corresponde a digitada, caso sim ele salvara e terá um break para sair do foreach naquele momento.

Código:

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Login

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(PassTxt.Text))
        {

            //Check if textbox is Empty
            var result = RJMessageBox.Show(" Please enter data for all fields ",
                "Error!!",
                MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            //Looping to get the match data using foreach
            FirebaseResponse response = client.Get("Users/");
            Dictionary<string, Registe> result = response.ResultAs<Dictionary<string, Registe>>();
            dynamic account;
            bool find = false;
            string userresult;
            string premiumresult;
            string passresult;
            string emailresult;
            string fnameresult;
            foreach (var get in result)
            {
                userresult = get.Value.username;
                premiumresult = get.Value.Premium;
                passresult = get.Value.password;
                emailresult = get.Value.email;
                fnameresult = get.Value.FullName;

                **// Erro, aparece a messageBox como entra no Formulario**
                if ((UserTxt.Text == userresult) && (PassTxt.Text == passresult))
                {
                    find = true; // Variavel para dizer que o valor foi encontrado
                    account = get; // Variavel que ira guardar os dados
                    break; // Break para sair dor Foreach
                }
            }
            if (find) {
                usernamepass = UserTxt.Text;
                fullname = fnameresult;
                pass = PassTxt.Text;
                mail = emailresult;
                RPre = premiumresult;

                if (RPre == "0")
                {
                    VPNFree VPNFree = new VPNFree();
                    this.Hide();
                    VPNFree.ShowDialog();
                }

                if (RPre == "1")
                {
                    VPN VPN = new VPN();
                    this.Hide();
                    VPN.ShowDialog();
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                var result2 = RJMessageBox.Show("Credentials do not exist",
                        "Error!!",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```